# error TS2305: Module '"react"' has no exported member 'Node'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I ran the React Native project along with the official documentation and added TypeScript to the project.
Many ESlint errors occurred when I was executing 'yarn tsc', for example:

```js
App.tsx:10:14 - error TS2305: Module '"react"' has no exported member 'Node'.

10 import type {Node} from 'react';
```

I know this is just an TS error, but I am confused, why does the code, 'import type {Node} from 'react';',  produce this error

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Because React doesn't export a type named `Node`. Maybe you are looking for `ReactNode`?

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gOQgExQXzgDMoIQ4ByKFAQwGMYKBuOAelbhSlKgFgAoUJFgJkadACVaDbHkIkylavUYt2cCAGsgA)

```ts
import type {Node} from 'react'; // error
import type {ReactNode} from 'react'; // ok
```

Answer (score 4):

try to add in `tsconfig.json`

`"skipLibCheck": true,`

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new standard project gives you an `App.js` with these lines:

```js
import type {Node} from 'react';
    
const App: () => Node = () => {
```

And the code works even if you remove the import.

I've checked the TS template created by:

> npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template
> react-native-template-typescript

It gives you an `App.tsx` with only

```
const App = () => {
```

I'm not digging the reason around the missing return type in TS, that is in fact a `React.ReactNode`

Comment: Should change from importing `Node` to importing `ReactNode`