# Type 'Set<unknown>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get all ids in Array, and then remove duplicates with React TypeScript.

Here is my code :

```
const uniqueMuscle = workoutexercices.map((exercice: any) => {
    let exercicesId = exercice.id;
    exercicesId = [...new Set(exercicesId)];
    return exercicesId;
  });
```

VSCode underlines `[...new Set(exercicesId)];` in red and tells me :
`Type 'Set<unknown>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher`

So I went to my `ts.config` and I changed the value, but still the same error.

Here is my `ts.config` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
I   "downlevelIteration": true
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Any idea why I keep having this error ?

Comment: I mean, that tsconfig doesn’t have `downlevelIteration` set and the `target` is `es5`, which is older than `es2015`.  So if that’s your TS config then of course you’d get that error.  You said you “changed the value”.  What value did you change and to what did you change it?

Comment: @jcalz I changed ez5 by es2015 and added "downlevelIteration": true ?

Comment: @Johan - Better to show that edited version *in* the question, than the one you already know doesn't work.

Comment: Also, what is `exercise.id`? You're using it as an iterable, passing it into `new Set`, and then using the values from the set in an array. That seems odd for an "id". I suppose if the ID is a string that would give you unique characters, but I can't imagine why that would be useful...

Comment: With `target: "es2015"` and `"downlevelIteration": true` (though you don't need it if targeting ES2015), [I don't get an error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xs7dts?file=index.ts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

had same error, setting tsconfig.json from CommonJS to Es modules with target, module, moduleResolution helped me.

my tsconfig.json:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

The problem is that you want to use a feature that is only available in the ES2015 JavaScript version onwards.

The solution is to update the tsconfig.json file, changing `"target"` to at least `"es2015"` (also called `"es6"`).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    ...
  }
}
```

Source: [TSConfig Target option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target)

Comment: what if I want to use it with es5, what should I do?

Comment: If you're using Next.js, and still facing this error after changing the target, then clear the next cache by doing `rm -rf .next` and it should work. Else you might be looking at the wrong tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 17):

try  `exercicesId = Array.from(new Set(exercicesId));`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Comment: Simple, readable solution. Docs link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 4):

For those who, as myself, for any reason can't change the target there are alternatives to fix this problem. It's, for instance, possible to remove all duplicates using the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. This exactly the first way to achieve that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/1128918) suggests.

Using the example proposed by the OP, here is what needs to be changed:

One can replace this:

```
exercicesId = [...new Set(exercicesId)];
```

With this:

```
exercicesId = exercicesId.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);
```

Answer (score 1):

(hijacking) adding a note for others finding this thread

In my React v 18.2 app  I got the similar error below when implementing the Recoiljs DebugObserver as described in https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/dev-tools#observing-all-state-changes

**type 'Iterable<RecoilValue>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.**

I turns out the Create react app set the configuration in tsconfig to **"target": "es5"**

When updating the target to 2019 or 2020 I got another error in the DebugObserver

- **Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'Node'.ts(2694)**
- **changing the use of "React.Node" to "React.ReactNode" solves the issue** as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70332268/2501481)
- *not sure if it is something that has changed in the versions of React or not.*

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRecoilSnapshot } from "recoil";

//function DebugObserver(): React.Node { // not working with es2019 or es2020
function DebugObserver(): React.ReactNode {
    const snapshot = useRecoilSnapshot();
    useEffect(() => {
      console.debug('The following atoms were modified:');
      for (const node of snapshot.getNodes_UNSTABLE({isModified: true})) {
        console.debug(node.key, snapshot.getLoadable(node));
      }
    }, [snapshot]);
  
    return null;
  }
```

So tsconfig.json ends up like this

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false, //setting this to false will show errors in node_modules,  
    //Consider setting "skipLibCheck" to false if you are using third-party libraries with TypeScript definitions. 
    //This will help you catch type errors in those libraries. 
    //However, if you encounter performance issues during the type-checking process, set it back to true.
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "react" //Add "jsxImportSource": "react" to use the new JSX transform introduced in React 17, which allows you to use JSX without importing React explicitly.
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is, go to `tsconfig.json` file and change the `es2015` to `es6`.

[image]

Comment: the question has been answered a long time ago, but thanks

Answer (score -1):

modify ts config file

```
...
"target": "ES2015",
"lib": [...,"ES2015"],
...
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't teach the asker anything they don't already know (see their title). 2) lib values corresponding to a target are implied by selecting that target ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)).